# HTML5/Flash image editor to integrate in my website

Tags: flash, html, image-editor

I'm looking for a simple flash or html5 image editor that I can integrate in my website. What I need is something that let's me upload an image and after it ends the upload it shows a preview, then it let's me do some simple modification, like crop it and add some text.

I've seen aviary and think it can helps, but I'm still looking for something else.
Can any one help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know its been 3 years but have you tried [ckEdit](http://ckeditor.com/)?